# How might I assume a "default value" when parsing using boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Let's say I have a grammar defined to something like:

```
some_rule := a b [c [d]]
```

where `c`, and `d` are optional and default to a certain value (let's say 14) if not given. Can I get it to default to the 14 if the value isn't given? I want the produced `std::vector` to always be of size 4.

The closest I've come is like the following:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), ascii::space_type> some_rule;
some_rule %= int_ >> int_ >> -int_ >> -int_;

// ...

some_other_rule = some_rule[&some_callback_for_int_vectors];
```

which will then get 0 for the optional values that didn't show up (I believe). I then change consecutive 0s at the end into 14. Not only is this horribly wrong, but it's also just not elegant. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you can do this with the `boost::qi::attr` auxiliary parser.

```
int default_value = 14;

qi::rule<Iterator, int(),              ascii::space_type> some_optional_rule;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), ascii::space_type> some_rule;

some_optional_rule %= int_ | attr(default_value);
some_rule          %= repeat(2)[int_] >> repeat(2)[some_optional_rule];
```

I'm still not sure if this is the *best* way to do this though.

Comment: For a first answer, you really did not choose simplicity!

Comment: I think he means this is the first question you've answered, and the question is not exactly C++ 101. :)